# Ionic native Video Editor plugin progress event not updating the dom UI

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic-native

I am working on an Ionic2 / cordova app.

I am using ionic native Video Editor plugin to compress a file. I am using progress event to listen total progress. The progress event is showing in console, but it is not updating the DOM.

```
this.videoEditor.transcodeVideo({
  fileUri: correctUrl,
  outputFileName: `output${Date.now()}.mp4`,
  outputFileType: VideoEditorOptions.OutputFileType.MPEG4,
  progress: (info: number) => {
    console.log(info);
      this.totalCompressed = Math.ceil(info * 100);
      console.log(this.totalCompressed);
  }
})

<span [innerHTML]="totalCompressed"></span>
```

I am not seeing span changing.

Please help.

Comment: I want to also compress video, is this plugin helpful?

Comment: @HSWarraich, yes this is very good. I got it working with Ionic2. :)